# 404 error when opening Singe Portfolio pages

Tags: troubleshooting

Had a website running for a few months... never had this problem... when I open a single portfolio page, it says Page not found .... like here: http://zemaraim.com/artwork/omotai/

Haven't installed anything in the last few days apart from Google Analytics Viewer plugin.... any pointers on why this might be happening? Cheers!

Comment: looks like it's working again?

Comment: Oh it does.... Restored a backup through my hosting providers site....

Comment: Not working again! After I restored the site, I updated some of the plugins (Duplicate Post and some other) ... it worked for a while .... its 404 times again... :(

Comment: visit your permalinks settings page, which will flush rewrite rules, and see if that makes it work again.